# Plain text when using the XML sitemap alternate language

Tags: xml, sitemap, multilingual

For a project I need to make a sitemap in XML. But I can't figure out the part with the alternate language. If I test the generated XML in a XML file the result is just plain text. Not even XML tags or something. So my question, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the instruction from Google I'm following: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

The XML code: http://pastebin.com/N9k1mFrS

And this is what I got as result: [image]

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You said "If I test the generated XML in a XML file the result is just plain text", how do you test that?